# How to find 4 lowest values of a list in C++ while keeping index

Tags: c++, list, indexing, min

I have a vector of 10 doubles and I need to find the four lowest values of the 10 while still keeping the index of the lowest values (so I can keep track of them later). In this case I can assume that all 10 values are unique. I tried creating a loop to do this but don't really know how to go from there. Any help would be appreciated.

```
            vector<double> double_vector {value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4,value_5,value_6,value_7,value_8,value_9,value_10};
            for (double x : double_vector)
            {
             /* What to do here */
            }
```

Comment: Can you sort the list? Then the 1st 4 elements will be the lowest values.  But why a `list` and not a `vector`?

Comment: If you can modify the list, sorting is overkill. You can use `std::nth_element` to find the first N elements. But (by itself) that won't keep track of their original indices.

Comment: @JerryCoffin `nth_element` requires random access iterators, but `list` is not a random access container

Comment: There may be some design considerations that should be revisited first.  If you want to _"keep track of them for later"_, I would recommend storing pointers or iterators, as `list`s are not designed to be _indexed_.  Also, a list of 10 doubles may not even have _"4 lowest values"_.  If all 10 values are `0.0`, which are the 4 lowest?

Comment: I don't have to use a list, vectors or pointers or iterators or whatnot is fine. Also in my case I don't need to worry if all 10 values are the same, all the values will be different.

Comment: @postfan you can still [edit] your question if it needs additional clarity.  Currently it's using `list`, while you may mean "some collection type" or "some ordered collection type".

Comment: If I give you 10 values written in a paper, how would you spot the 4 lowest ones? And if I give them to you one by one?

Comment: Question has been edited.

Comment: Sort the vector (presumably there are no **NaN** in there, if so you'll need a special compare to handle that case).  Select the first 4 values.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I generally treat use of `std::list` as a mistake, since it usually is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the priority queue of size 4 (max heap). Iterate over your array and insert into the heap. If heap size is 5 then remove the top element. Repeat. In the end in your prio queue (heap) will remain the lowest elements.
Time complexity is O(n) as the heap is of constant size.

Don't forget to store an index in your heap together with the value. The comparison however should be based on the value only...

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <tuple>

struct Compare{
    bool operator () (const std::pair<int, int>& lhs, const std::pair<int, int>& rhs) const{
        return lhs.first < rhs.first;
    }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v = {5,3,1,2,3,45,2,4};
  std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>, Compare> q;
  for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
      q.push(std::make_pair(v[i], i));
      if(q.size() > 4){
          q.pop();
      }
  }
  
  while(!q.empty()){
      auto e = q.top();
      std::cout << e.first << " " << e.second << std::endl;
      q.pop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `vector<int>` of the same size as your `vector<double>`, assign sequential numbers (indexes) starting from `0`.

Sort that index vector using a custom compare function that compares elements of the `double` vector indexed by the values in the index vector. If you only need a small number of elements from the `double` vector, even a bubble sort will work. Or just use `std::sort()`. Or better yet, as @Sebastian suggested, use `std::partial_sort()`.

Comment: or even `std::partial_sort`

Comment: Bubble sort will be O(n^2) no matter how many elements you need from it.  Not recommended.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think for first 4 elements it will be O(4*n), or O(n)

Comment: Worst case for bubble sort will be when the vector is in reverse order to start.  Each pass will only move an element one position, so there will be n passes over n elements.  You can't stop until those 4 elements are in the proper position.  Thus O(n^2).

Comment: @MarkRansom in 1 pass I can move the smallest element to the 1st position, in second - second, and so on. Note : I am not pushing that bubble sort

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the vector. If you want the indices you can sort a `std::vector<std::pair<Index,Value>>` with respect to `Value`s from the original vector. As you are only looking for the first 4, you can use `std::partial_sort`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    
    std::vector<double> double_vector {1.5,1.3,1.2,1.7,1.1,1.4,1.9,1.8,1.0};
    
    std::vector<std::pair<double,size_t>> temp;
    for (size_t i=0;i<double_vector.size();++i)
    {
        temp.emplace_back(double_vector[i],i);
    }
    std::partial_sort(temp.begin(),temp.begin()+4,temp.end());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        std::cout << temp[i].second << " " << temp[i].first << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xE5efWzef)

When the vector is very large, you can consider to use a `priority_queue<std::pair<Index,Value>>` to only ever store 4 values and pop of the smallest while updating it.

Comment: With `std::pair<Value, Index>` (changing order), you can keep default comparer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this if you cannot change the  initial vector - although it is not very elegant. It returns a vector of integers containing the indexes of the lowest values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Receives a vector of doubles and how many of the lowest doubles needed
// Returns a vector containing the indexes of the lowest doubles
vector<int> get_four_lowest_values(const vector<double>& double_vector, int lowest) {

    int highest_index = 0;
    vector<int> index_vector;

    // Return empty vector on bad input
    if(double_vector.size() < lowest) {
        return index_vector;
    }

    // Populate index vector with the first n index elements
    for(int i = 0; i < lowest; i++) {
        index_vector.push_back(i);
    }

    // Find the max of the first n elements of the double_vector
    for(int i = 0; i < lowest; i++) {
        if(double_vector[highest_index] < double_vector[i]) {
            highest_index = i;
        }
    }

    // Iterate over the rest of the vector
    for(int i = lowest; i < double_vector.size(); i++) {

        // Remove max and replace it with something lower
        if(double_vector[i] < double_vector[index_vector[highest_index]]) {
            index_vector[highest_index] = i;
            highest_index = 0;

            // Find new max
            for(int j = 1; j < lowest; j++) {
                if(double_vector[index_vector[j]] > double_vector[index_vector[highest_index]]) {
                    highest_index = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return index_vector;
}


int main() {

    int lowest = 4;

    vector<double> double_vector = {0.35, 15.42, 37.55, 44.555, 0.3456, 444,
        54.55, 0.1201, 0.55, 14};

    vector<int> index_vector = get_four_lowest_values(double_vector, lowest);

    for(int i = 0; i < lowest; i++) {
        cout << double_vector[index_vector[i]] << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
map<double, int> smallest;
vector<double> double_vector {value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4,value_5,value_6,value_7,value_8,value_9,value_10};
for (int i=0;i<double_vector.size();i++) 
{
    smallest.insert(pair<double, int>(double_vector[i], i));
}
```

Now the first 4 elements in `smallest` will contain the value of the smallest in `double_vector` and their corresponding indexes.